# Thunderbird: Delete Emails from Certain Address

Tags: thunderbird, email

I have the Latest Thunderbird in 13.04 and certain addresses are spamming my mails. I want each time TB connects to delete mail from those addresses. Note that not all junk mails but from specific addresses regardless of where they are (inbox, junks et al). Is there a tool I can use for that?

Deleting them at startup is becoming a burden. TB's Junk controls don't work, unless I miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a filter with the [Quick Filter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quickfilters) free extension for Thunderbird.

You may also wish to add a toolbar button, and [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/message-filters-button/) makes that easy.

Comment: let me try and see how its doing